# React app rendering html entities such as ampersand as escaped

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, utf-8, escaping

I have a React app embedded in Wordpress page. It  pulls content from a JSON api and displays it in various areas.

My problem is that all of the text content that comes from the api displays as escaped charachters i.e `&#038;` displays where an ampersand should be.

My wordpress page has `<meta charSet="utf-8" />` which I would normally expect to convert this, but is having no effecton the React content. Is it because the rendering is done within React? In which case do I need to set React somehow to be using UTF-8?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

HTML (including entities) will be rendered as a string when being rendered as an expression:

```
{htmlString}
```

In order to parse HTML, there is [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) prop:

```
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlString }} />
```

As the name says, it's unsafe and should be generally avoided. If a string comes from untrusted source or a source that could be exploited, malicious code can be rendered to a client.

The preferable way is to decode entities specifically, e.g. with [`html-entities`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities):

```
import { Html5Entities } from 'html-entities';
const htmlEntities = new Html5Entities();

...

{htmlEntities.decode(htmlString)}
```

The problem could be avoided by not storing HTML entities in the first place if possible.

Comment: Brilliant, decode solved it. Thank you! Moving forward I'll try and set up the API's to remove html at source.

Comment: This answer solved my problem as well. Thanks a lot! Just what I was looking for.