# react native currency symbol not printing from variable

Tags: variables, react-native, text, currency

I want to print currency symbol from its currency code.
but it not working from variable.

**My Code:-**

```
render() {
  var currencyCode = "&#36;"
  return (
      <View>
        <Text>{currencyCode}</Text>
        <Text>&#36;</Text>
      </View>
  )
}
```

**Output:-**
[image]

if enter static currency code so it is working but not working from variable.

> How to print currency symbol from variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React app rendering html entities such as ampersand as escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467082/react-app-rendering-html-entities-such-as-ampersand-as-escaped)

Comment: above link for webpage but i'm using react native mobile application

Comment: See [Render HTML in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334984/render-html-in-react-native)

Comment: The answer in dupe question explains all options. There are three of them. If you can't use dangerouslysetinnerhtml in React Native then you have only two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467082/react-app-rendering-html-entities-such-as-ampersand-as-escaped) explains all available options. Since `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is inapplicable in React Native, there are only two of them.

HTML entities can be specifically decoded, e.g. with `html-entities`:

```
import { Html5Entities } from 'html-entities';
const htmlEntities = new Html5Entities();

...

{htmlEntities.decode(htmlString)}
```

The problem can be avoided by not storing HTML entities in the first place if possible. Currency symbols are valid Unicode characters and can be stored as such:

```
var currencyCode = "€"; // &#8364;
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you should use unicoded symbols as shown in [this tutorial](https://reactnativecode.com/show-dollar-rupees-euro-currency-symbols/)